# Form with file attachment and size and type verification issues with script

Tags: php, forms, file, upload, attachment

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. The script in my little head seems to be okay. I can get it to work without file validation if I remove part of the script. Can anyone put some light into it please? I am a novice.

HTML part:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" method="post">
    <p><label for="file">Select file to upload</label> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="send"></p>
    </form>
```

process.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_FILES['file'])) {
$errors = array();
$maxsize = 4096000;
$acceptable = array(
    'application/pdf',
    'msword/doc',
    'msword/docx',
    'text/plain'
);

if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["file"]["size"] == 0)) {
    $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 4 megabytes.';
}

if(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES["file"]["type"])) {
    $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only pdf, doc, docx and txt files are accepted.';
}

if(count($errors) === 0)

{

    $to = 'test@hotmail.com';
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: info@example.com\r\nReply-To: info@example";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
    }

    die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
}
}
?>
```

Comment: So you mean if you remove two `if` blocks of validation, then the email will be sent?

Comment: If I remove the first part all the way up to if(count($errors) === 0) and the last part else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
    }

    die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
}, The it will send fine as long as I still keep if(isset($_POST['submit'] from the first part.

Comment: You've wrote that _I can get it to work without file validation if I remove part of the script_. So I can see that the two `if` block are the only file validation in your code(`if(($_FILES['file']['size'] >= $maxsize)...` and `if(!in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $acceptable))...`). My question is if you remove these two `if` statements, will the file get attached to email and be sent?

Comment: OK, if you do not remove those parts and just add `var_dump($errors); die();` before this line `if(count($errors) === 0)` what will you see on screen?

Comment: I get HTTP Error 500. Page isnt working. I have to remove the the 2 if validations and the last else statement to get it to send.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is shown if your php code has fatal errors but error displaying is switched off. Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your page and then see what is your error

Comment: Hi, thanks for your efforts. I have added the code for error reporting and still the same.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND) in.../process.php on line 17

Comment: I can not help you unless I see the related code...